# How to set up PlayN size

Tags: playn

I've tried :

```
graphics().setSize(800, 600);
```

But it has no effects (at least with java and html).

And it seems this method is deprecated. What is the best way to set up the game size ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This method was deprecated in version 1.5 of PlayN, the size of your game view on Android/iOS is dictated by the device. The size on Java is configured via JavaPlatform.Config. The size in HTML is configured by the size of your playn-root div.

For example on the java backend:

```
public class GameJava {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
//Setting the size of the Java Backend
      Config config = new Config();
      config.width = 800;
      config.height = 480;
    JavaPlatform platform = JavaPlatform.register(config);
    platform.assets().setPathPrefix("your/package/resources");
    PlayN.run(new Game());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works fine for java. But for html, how do I set the root element size ? I add a javascript link to patch the size, or can I access the rootElement from java ?

Answer (score 3):

for HTML do something like this:

```
<style>
  #playn-root {
    width: 640px;
    height: 480px;
  }
</style>
....
<div id="playn-root"></div>
<body>
    <script src="game/game.nocache.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you @Shaga. The div element was missing from a project built from archetype.